# Upload de Imagens com fundo transparente

Tags: imagem

Estou idealizando um sistema em que o usuário deve fazer o upload de uma imagem, mas essa imagem deve ser com o fundo transparente, pois desejo usa-la para sobre por outra imagem. Não sei como fazer isso, ainda não tive nenhuma ideia.

Comment: O que você já tentou?

Comment: Você precisa só do css pra deixar a imagem transparente ?

Comment: Ainda não tenho nada de concreto. Testei a penas alguns códigos que vi na internet. Ainda estou na parte de idealização. Poderia ser só com css, desde que a imagem ficasse transparante depois do upload.

Answer (score 0):

Estou fazendo um trabalho que tem o que você precisa e essa parte de imagens é simples, depois que vi entendi fácil:

```
if ($_POST['cadastrar']) {

$foto = $_FILES["foto"];

if (!empty($foto["name"])) {

    // Largura máxima em pixels
    $largura = 1500;
    // Altura máxima em pixels
    $altura = 1800;
    // Tamanho máximo do arquivo em bytes
    $tamanho = 900000;

    // Verifica se o arquivo é uma imagem
    if(!preg_match("/^image\/(pjpeg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)$/", $foto["type"])){
       $error[1] = "Isso não é uma imagem.";
    } 

    // Pega as dimensões da imagem
    $dimensoes = getimagesize($foto["tmp_name"]);

    // Verifica se a largura da imagem é maior que a largura permitida
    if($dimensoes[0] > $largura) {
        $error[2] = "A largura da imagem não deve ultrapassar ".$largura." pixels";
    }

    // Verifica se a altura da imagem é maior que a altura permitida
    if($dimensoes[1] > $altura) {
        $error[3] = "Altura da imagem não deve ultrapassar ".$altura." pixels";
    }

    // Verifica se o tamanho da imagem é maior que o tamanho permitido
    if($foto["size"] > $tamanho) {
        $error[4] = "A imagem deve ter no máximo ".$tamanho." bytes";
    }

    if (count(@$error) == 0) {

        // Pega extensão da imagem
        preg_match("/\.(gif|bmp|png|jpg|jpeg){1}$/i", $foto["name"], $ext);

        // Gera um nome único para a imagem
        $nome_imagem = md5(uniqid(time())) . "." . $ext[1];

        // Caminho de onde ficará a imagem
        $caminho_imagem = "fotos/" . $nome_imagem;

        // Faz o upload da imagem para seu respectivo caminho
        move_uploaded_file($foto["tmp_name"], $caminho_imagem);

        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES ('', '".$nome_imagem."')");

        if ($sql){
            echo "Você foi cadastrado com sucesso.";
        }
    }

    if (count(@$error) != 0) {
        foreach ($error as $erro) {
            echo $erro . "<br />";
        }
    }
}
}
```

Lembrando que vc vai precisar criar uma pasta dentro da pasta que está o sistema para alocar as fotos, no caso a pasta fotos, como está onde o comentário diz caminho onde ficará a imagem

Comment: Não funcionou :/

Comment: você colocou dentro do php esse código? Ali onde está (pjpeg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp) deixou só png? png que eu saiba é o único formato que suporta transparencia

Answer (score 0):

A imagem terá fundo transparente se for feita no formato PNG. Você pode fazer uma verificação quando o usuário fizer upload da imagem, garantindo que a imagem esteja no formato PNG. Deve ser especificado ao usuário que a imagem deve ter fundo transparente.

Acredito que não seja possível pegar uma imagem com fundo colorido e deixá-la com fundo transparente sem usar alguma software de edição de imagem.